# What does 'refresh' mean in the mysql query log?

Tags: mysql

I'm looking at the log of a mysql server and we have full query logging going on. We're running mysqldump on it to back it up. Right before the server restarts itself, there's an entry in the query log `Refresh`. What does that mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Refresh` indicates that MySQLd is flushing all tables, closing all logs files and then re-opening log files.

It is a protocol level command (`COM_REFRESH`) that can be called from [mysqladmin](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqladmin.html#command_mysqladmin_refresh) and acts similar to a combination of the SQL commands `FLUSH TABLES; FLUSH LOGS;`.

You can find some details in the privileges document [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_reload).